# User creation does not work on laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, authentication, import, laravel-5.1

actually i try to migrate some users from a excel file (.xlsx) to login in my aplication. But the code doesn't work.
The strange part is that the same code it's implemented for migrate payroll from a excel file (.xlsx) and this one work. I try many options, change some code, but it doesn't work.
Maybe I'm letting some error out and someone else can see it. I would appreciate the help.

Edit: I have a code in my routes.php that performs the migration, but from a table in the database, and this one works

My routes.php

```
Route::get("user_mig", function()
{
    $contr = temporalestla\ContractUser::all();
    foreach ($contr as $value)
    {
        $psw = \Hash::make($value->id_employee);
        $user = new temporalestla\User
        ([
            "full_name"=>$value->name_used,
            "user" => $value->id_employee,
            "password" => $psw,
            "perfil" => 1
        ]);
        $user->save();
    }
    return "Proceso finalizado";
});
```

My ImportController.php from users

```
public function cargar_datos_users(Request $request)
    {
        $file= $request->file('file');
        $original_name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $r1=Storage::disk('files')->put($original_name,  \File::get($file) );
        $route=  storage_path('files') ."/". $original_name;
        if($r1)
        {
            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($route, function($sheet)
            {
                $sheet->each(function($row)
                {
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->full_name = $row->nombreempleado;
                    $user->user = $row->empleado;
                    $user->password = bcrypt($row->empleado);
                    $perfil = 1;
                    $user->perfil = $perfil;
                    $user->save();
                });
            });
            return view("administrator.contracts.adminpayrolls")->with("msj","Usuarios Cargados Correctamente");             
        }
        else
        {
            return view("administrator.contracts.adminpayrolls")->with("msj","Error al subir el archivo");
        }
    }
```

My app/User.php

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['full_name', 'user', 'password','perfil'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

The ajax script located in view.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit",".formarchivo",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formu=$(this);
        var nombreform=$(this).attr("id");
        if(nombreform=="f_cargar_datos_users" ){ var miurl="cargar_datos_users";  var divresul="notificacion_resul_fcdu"}
        var formData = new FormData($("#"+nombreform+"")[0]);
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: miurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#"+divresul+"").html($("#cargador_empresa").html());
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("Usuarios cargados correctamente");
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("Error al subir usuarios. intente nuevamente");
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

The plugin for migrate from excel is http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs
As I said, the same structure work on payroll migrate, but don't work on users migrate, any comments will be appreciate.

Comment: you missed a closing `});` after $user->save();

Comment: Thanks dude! , i miss that ' }`  , i fix it, but the code still not working

Comment: and the error is changed? what is the error now? please edit your question and provide more details

Comment: You add a `}` but you had to add `});` please read carefully my first comment

Comment: Actually i cannot see the error, because i send the parameters through ajax but i post it now